# Is it required to update Dart SDK for VScode?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

When I check dart and flutter version from VScode it shows

> Dart VM version: 2.7.0 (Fri Dec 6 16:26:51 2019 +0100) on
> "windows_x64"
>
> Flutter 2.0.5 • channel stable •
> https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git Framework • revision adc687823a
> (12 days ago) • 2021-04-16 09:40:20 -0700 Engine • revision b09f014e96
> Tools • Dart 2.12.3

But when I run VScode it prompts me to update Dart SDK

> Version 2.12.4 of the Dart SDK is available (you have 2.7.0). Some
> features of Dart Code may not work correctly with an old SDK.

At the same time the dart sdk page says

> As of Flutter 1.21, the Flutter SDK includes the full Dart SDK. So if
> you have Flutter installed, you might not need to explicitly download
> the Dart SDK. Consider downloading the Dart SDK if any of the
> following are true:
>
> - You don’t use Flutter.
> - You use a pre-1.21 version of Flutter.
> - You want to reduce disk space requirements or download time, and your    use case doesn’t require Flutter. For example, you might have
>   a    continuous integration (CI) setup that requires Dart but not
>   Flutter.

So should I update dart sdk? But as it says `if you have Flutter installed, you might not need to explicitly download the Dart SDK`, it' a litle bit confused., because I have Flutter installed.

Answer (score 0):

You no longer need to download a separate dart SDK.  Remove it (at least move it out of the way), and do `flutter upgrade`.  If "dart --version" still works, you're golden, although you may need to remove any manually-set dart SDK paths.  I'm pretty sure all the supported IDE extensions for Dart pick up the proper "buried within flutter" paths for the Dart SDK.